# TypeError: removeDuplicates() missing 1 required positional argument: 'randList'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am fairly new to Python and need help. I have searched the web for several days which helped fixed previous errors but I am still stuck on this one. I know this has been asked several times and I have read the forums; however, I still can't solve this problem.

I am using Python 3.4.4

The goal for this assignment is to create a random list of 50 numbers ranging from 1-100 and print it. Then you have to take that same list and remove the duplicate numbers and print that list as well. Ultimately, 2 lists should be printed, one with duplicates, one without. Here is my code:

```
from random import randrange

def createList():
    print("A program that will generate a list of 50 random numbers then remove any duplicates.")
    for i in range(50):
        randList = randrange(101)
        print(randList)

def removeDuplicates(randList):
    uniqueList = []
    for i in randList:
        if i not in uniqueList:
            uniqueList.append(i)
    print(uniqueList)

def main():
    createList()
    removeDuplicates()

if __name__ == "__main__": main()
```

Here is my error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python34/Python Assignments/test-randNumbs.py", line 20, in <module>
    if __name__ == "__main__": main()
  File "C:/Python34/Python Assignments/test-randNumbs.py", line 18, in main
    removeDuplicates()
TypeError: removeDuplicates() missing 1 required positional argument: 'randList'
```

Comment: your function definition `removeDuplicates()` has been given no arguments when called from `main`

Comment: Here are some suggestions. `createList` should create a list and return it to `main`. Then `main` should call `removeDuplicates` passing it the list it got from `createList`.`removeDuplicates` should return the `uniqueList` to `main`. Let `main` do _all_ the printing; that `print("A program that will generate...")` stuff doesn't belong in `createList`

Comment: Thank you for clarifying what needed to be fixed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to pass a list to your `removeDuplicates()` function. However, to do that you also need to return a randomly created list in the `createList()`.

```
from random import randrange

def create_list():
    rand_list = []
    print("A program that will generate a list of 50 random numbers then remove any duplicates.")
    for i in range(50):
        rand_list.append(randrange(101))
    print(rand_list)
    return rand_list

def remove_duplicates(rand_list):
    unique_list = []
    for i in rand_list:
        if i not in unique_list:
            unique_list.append(i)
    print(unique_list)

def main():
    rand_list = create_list()
    print('unique list:')
    remove_duplicates(rand_list)

if __name__ == "__main__": main()
```